# UPDATE campo tipo INT a NULL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy editando un registro que contiene un campo tipo `INT` para lo cual uso

```
$stmt->bindParam(5, $qte_cntId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

sucede que el campo, en algunos casos, puede ser `NULL` entonces me retorna el error `Incorrect integer value` obviamente si lo valido como `NULL`

```
$stmt->bindParam(5, $qte_cntId, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

si `$qte_cntId` viene con valor `!= NULL` lo deja en `NULL`

Como lo valido para que lo actualice correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

Usando el operador ternario:

```
$stmt->bindParam(5, $qte_cntId, isset($qte_cntId) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

Comment: Asi funciona bien!